# Email notifications for expiry item on K2 (Joomla )

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2

Is there anyway to email the author of the item/article about the upcoming expiry of an item?

Comment: Thank you for joining us on JSE.  Please take our [tour]. As I mentioned on your StackOverflow question, your question demonstrate no proof of research and no attempt to self-solve.  Sometimes volunteers are willing to go to great lengths to offer a solution, but generally we ask that you show what you tried and isolate where you are stuck so that the effort required of the volunteers here is minimised.  Please [edit] your question to make answering more attractive.

Comment: The Item has extra field type date which holds the expire date of the item